# Pointer to function instead if in c

Tags: c

I'm making a little calculator in C with only "+, -, /, *, %" parameters, and honestly, this is working fine. But I would try to make it with pointer to function I think I will use a better syntax but I don't know where I may start and how can I do/can I use it? I would like improve myself.

Someone can explain me please?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     ft_atoi(char *str);
void    ft_putnbr(int nb);

int check_by_zero(int a, int b, char oper)
{
    int res;

    if (oper == '/')
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            write(1, "Stop : division by zero\n", 24);
            res = -1;
        }
        else
            res = a / b;
    }
    if (oper == '%')
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            write(1, "Stop : modulo by zero\n", 22);
            res = -1;
        }
        else
            res = a % b;
    }
    return (res);
}

int do_result(int a, int b, char oper)
{
    int res;

    if (oper == '-')
        res = a - b;
    if (oper == '+')
        res = a + b;
    if (oper == '/' || oper == '%')
        res = check_by_zero(a, b, oper);
    if (oper == '*')
        res = a * b;
    return (res);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int     value1;
    int     value2;
    int     res;
    char    c;

    if (ac != 4)
        return (0);
    value1 = ft_atoi(av[1]);
    value2 = ft_atoi(av[3]);
    c = av[2][0];
    if ((!(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*'
        || c == '/' || c == '%')) || av[2][1] != 0)
        res = 0;
    else
        res = do_result(value1, value2, c);
    if (res != -1)
    {
        ft_putnbr(res);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

EDIT: Can't use standard function. Only mine. This is the reason why I use write instead printf

Comment: You could simplify the big `if` condition in the `main` function a little bit, if you learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: And what is the reason you use `write` to write your output rather than `printf`? What is your assignment? What are its requirements and limitations?

Comment: Note: `if (b == 0)` is a good check for `/`, but code is missing the `INT_MIN/-1` check.

Comment: It might be a candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you post the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> make it with pointer to function

Create a function for each operator.

```
int hh_div(int a, int b) {
  // TBD: add some checks
  return a / b;
}

int hh_add(int a, int b) {
  // TBD: add some checks
  return a + b;
}
```

Then use an [array of function pointers](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*all%5B256%5D%29%28int%2C+int%29) indexed by `char oper`.

```
int do_it(char oper, int a, int b) {
  static const int (*all[256])(int, int) = { //
        ['/'] = hh_div, //
        ['+'] = hh_add, //
        // etc
  };
  int (*f)(int a, int b) = all[(unsigned char) oper];
  if (f == NULL) {
    Handle_NotDefined();
  }
  return f(a, b);
}
```

---

Code could use a big `if()` or `switch()`, but with a nice function look-up table, what is a 1 or 2 k-byte table between friends?

Of course the table could be smaller with some pre-tests.

Ref: Some 2 operand operators: `% ^ & * + - | \ < > /`

Comment: Thank you so much for your responde, but how to assignate them on by one, is this something like this: 
int (*all[127])(int, int);
all[0] = {['+'] = do_plus};

Comment: @hugohg Yes: Answer shows 2 initializations: `['/'] = hh_div,  ['+'] = hh_add`.  Simply extend that with `['/'] = hh_div, ['+'] = hh_add, ['*'] = hh_mul,  ['-'] = hh_sub,` and  others like `% ^ &  |  < >`.

Comment: @hugohg As `char` has 256 different values, your `all[127]` poses trouble when `oper` is not in the range 0-126.

Comment: 127 is for signed char I know what I set in oper. But it doesnt work when I try to initialized them manually, i have error expression: all[0] = {['+'] = do_plus} ;

Comment: @hugohg _Initialization_ is done when the object is defined.  _Assignment_ is later, done with `=`.  `int (*all[256])(int, int) = { ['+'] = hh_plus}` to initialize.   `all['+'] = do_plus;` to assign.  If you get an error, do not just _describe_ the error with "i have error expression", report the error message exactly.  Good luck GTG.